# how to get the position of a particular string in the editor that is currently opened?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m doing a project using eclipse plugin to create a IDE.

I have a view which consists of a textbox,when i enter some text in it and press the add button the text should replace a particular string in the editor.
I m able to find the current editor but i dono how to find the position of the string to be replaced.

Can anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than do this yourself, wouldn't it be easier to use [`String.replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to do the replacement?

All you'd need to do is "get" the current text `String` from the target editor, do the replacement and then "set" the resulting `String` back to the target editor.

I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but most text fields will probably implement an abstract class like [`JTextComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) which has handy methods to [`getText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28java.lang.String%29) and [`setText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: is there any standard functions for that?

Comment: this **is** the standard function!

Comment: should i create instances of BufferedReader and InputStream for calling the above function?

Comment: that is not necessary, see the changes to my answer above

Comment: actually i know to get the information from the textbox,what i need is i need to get a particular string that is already present in the file that is currently opened and replace that string with the string entered in the textbox.

Comment: you don't need to read the file, you just need to get and modify the String from the text box. If you need to change the file, you can do that once you have the correct text in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the reference to the editor, and if it is an ITextEditor you can use

```
 IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();
 IDocument doc = provider.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
 String content = doc.get();
```

Now you have the content and you are able to find the position of some code within this string.

If you have the offset to replace the text and the length to replace you can call

```
 doc.replace(offset,length,newText);
```

If you work with Editors and Views in eclipse, please read first the concepts of an Editor, and how the data is provided and shared among mutliple editors.

Adreamus

/edit: I am not able to post a comment, though I will post it here: The other answer from Paul Webster uses a deprecated function "search". It is recommendet to use a [FindReplaceDocumentAdapter](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/FindReplaceDocumentAdapter.html) instead. The method  'find' returns an IRegion, wchich contains the offset and length in the document connected with this Adapter.